# Error when setting up X & Y axis in iOS-Charts (Xcode 7.3.1)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charts, ios-charts

I'm very new to coding, so I'm sorry if this is a basic question. I am using iOS-Charts by Daniel Gindi (the most recent version on his Github) to set up a bar graph using the following code:

```
    import UIKit
    import Charts

    class BarChartViewController: UIViewController {

        var barChartView: BarChartView!
        var days: [String]!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
            let tasks = [1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 0.0]

            setChart(days, values: tasks)
        }

        func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

            barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

            var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = Array()
            var counter = 0.0

            for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
                counter += 1.0
                let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: values[i], y: counter)
                dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
            }

            let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Time")
            let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: days, dataSet: chartDataSet)
            barChartView.data = chartData
        }
    }
```

This prompts an error in func setChart:

In

```
    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Time")
```

Incorrect argument in call (have yVals, expected values). But if you change yVals to values, it prompts an error in the next line:

```
    let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: days, dataSet: chartDataSet)
```

The error is: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'BarChartData' with an argument list of type '(xVals:[String]!, dataSet: BarChartDataSet)'

I took a look at ChartsDemo, but I'm not sure what I am exactly looking for (and I seem to be getting a compiling error when I try to build the demo).

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = Array()
    var counter = 0.0

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        counter += 1.0
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: values[i], y: counter)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Time")
    let chartData = BarChartData()
    chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
    barChartView.data = chartData

}
```

Comment: The code you gave me worked, but other parts of my code are giving the following error:

        'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)'

I can't seem to pin it down, it appears for:

        'barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."'

and     

        'barChartView.data = chartData'

Could you help me with this?

Comment: I tied this code on a mac and it works perfectly fine  https://gist.github.com/chaithanyaprathyush/5c4f25928460bb8086e11138b7fe7c57

Comment: I'm still having issues where "barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."" and "barChartView.data = chartData" are giving the error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" -> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I ran the code you made on a tutorial project (https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ehz8ca5g4npoc2/iOSChartsDemoStarter.zip?dl=0)... is it because of the format since mime is for iOS and yours is for OSX? I uploaded my test code to https://github.com/ghcjuba/barChartExample... I'm sorry about the continuing issues, and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: In your sample code, There was no IBOutlet connecting the BarChartView in the storyboard and the code in the BarChartViewController. So when the code got executed, the program was not able to find the BarChartView, hence the fatal error. Just control drag from the BarChartView in the storyboard over your existing IBOutlet object for the barchart view in the controller.

Comment: Got it working, but is there a way to change the x-axis to Strings? It seems like it only supports numerical values.

Comment: Could you be more explicit. You want to show string values instead of the actual values? You could also have a look at https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki. The iOS charts is based on the Android charts, check out the documents.

Comment: I'll check it out - thank you so much for your help! :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
        let chartData = BarChartData()
        chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
        
        barChart.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)
        chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
        barChart.data = chartData
```

full code

```html
//
//  ChartViewController.swift
//  OEE
//
//  Created by Andrew on 07.03.2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Andrew. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation
import Charts

class ChartViewController: UIViewController, IAxisValueFormatter, ChartViewDelegate {
    
    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return months[Int(value)]
    }
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var barChart: BarChartView!
    
    var months: [String]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
        let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]
        
        //setChart(months, values: unitsSold) missing argument label dataPoints: in call
        setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)
    }
    
    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
        barChart.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."
        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
        var counter = 0.0
        
        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            counter += 1.0
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: values[i], y: counter)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }
        
        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
        let chartData = BarChartData()
        chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
        
        barChart.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)
        chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
        barChart.data = chartData
        //barChart.xAxis.ent
        barChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: months)
        barChart.xAxis.labelCount = months.count
        barChart.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom

    
}
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.